# YouTube API html5 desktop click video area vs Android Chrome touch video area for pause

Tags: youtube-api

I can't find a simple yes/no answer - maybe my inability to ask the right question. I'm probably not seeing the obvious.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

If I set-up the iframe api example as per the linked page, with an appropriate header (e.g. viewport etc.) then when I view the page in Chrome on the desktop, I can click on the video area to play, and pause the video.  I do not need to use the play/pause control.

If I view the same site on my Note 4, I can touch the video area to play.  But in order to pause, I have to click on the (now tiny) pause control. Touching the video area does nothing.

I know I can programmatically add some other element and initiate a pause via the API ... but I don't think I can add a touch or onclick event to the player ... and the player state change event won't be any good if the player isn't changing state on subsequent touches?

Yes / No (trying to keep within non-vague / discursive guidelines) ... is it possible, without "hacks" to pause the video, on mobile, with a touch to the video area?

I suspect not, as YouTube's own site, on my Note 4, behaves in the same way.  I just can't find any discussion/questions about it.  I ask the question, as it seems counter-intuitive to reduce the control area on a smaller touch device for pausing.  It's annoying to me ... trying to use embedded YouTube in CSS3D where I have a video-wall 2x2 and the controls become tiny. I might have to overlay a transparent control element for touch but just want to check I haven't gone mad.